# Installing PhoneGap on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to install PhoneGap on eclipse in Ubuntu 13, I added this: 
https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2.9/download/ but after 3 or 4 minutes got the error what you see in image: [image] and now what the is solution for this? thanks in advance

Comment: you can build the phonegap project without installing phonegap on eclipse, by just including cordova in your library and calling loadUrl() method, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes but when i adding platform for my app i got the problem

Comment: you are getting error while stting up SDK, not phonegap! did u tried by  restarting your eclipse?

Comment: I am using eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) for android

Comment: aaha, you found the problem.... its your version mismatch.. my suggesion posted below, try out . :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are using Luna version V4.4 above, but your search was for for indigo version its V3.7, you have to go for luna version, here is the link to setup Luna version : (official)

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started

http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/getting-started-with-the-android-sdk-and-plugins-for-eclipse.aspx

trying to download lower_version_plugin for a later version is your problem.

hope the above links will fix your problem,  or try to google to set up eclipse Luna,